# Endless event loop in laravel when artisan queue:work runned

Tags: php, laravel, events, php-carbon

When I run php artisan queue:work I get endless loop of published event which is App\Events\PikirPublished

I couldn't find where I made a mistake. But in my log I saw that it is because of Carbon.

[image: When I run php artisan queue:work]

```
[2017-08-09 14:43:20] local.ERROR: InvalidArgumentException: Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
The separation symbol could not be found
Trailing data in /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php:582
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(709): Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', 'Sun, 06 Aug 201...')
#1 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(122): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->asDateTime('Sun, 06 Aug 201...')
#2 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(84): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->addDateAttributesToArray(Array)
#3 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(900): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->attributesToArray()
#4 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(929): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->toArray()
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->jsonSerialize()
#6 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/RedisBroadcaster.php(95): json_encode(Array)
#7 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastEvent.php(48): Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\RedisBroadcaster->broadcast(Array, 'App\\Events\\Piki...', Array)
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent->handle(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\RedisBroadcaster))
#9 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#11 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#12 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#13 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#14 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(114): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#15 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#16 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#17 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(42): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent), false)
#18 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(69): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Array)
#19 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(317): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#20 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(267): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#21 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(113): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), 'redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#22 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('redis', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#23 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(84): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('redis', 'default')
#24 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire()
#25 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#26 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#27 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#28 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#29 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(182): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#30 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(264): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#31 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(167): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#32 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(874): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#33 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(228): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(130): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#35 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#36 /Users/akmyradov/code/pikirler-desktop/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#37 {main}
```

Comment: Chances are there's an issue with the event data passed and you have failed que items to be retried unlimited times

Comment: @apokryfos is there any way to find that issue?

Comment: @apokryfos I even removed the line where this event is broadcasted

Comment: Kill your queue worker and try running it again with limited retries e.g. `php artisan queue:work --tries=3` and see if the event is only processed 3  times.

Comment: @apokryfos It logged 4 times that it is Failed

Comment: @apokryfos thank you man. Now it stopped when to run in a loop. Thank you for your help